# can you change the name of the Django admin 'is_staff' flag

Tags: python, django

I need to change the name of the is_staff flag in django admin.

Comment: it's not flag it's a user table field in django

Comment: As per the comment above, it's a field in the user model. Please provide more details about what you're trying to do, as there may be a way to help but you've given us very limited information to go on. Thanks